# Switch from LevelDB to CouchDB in a hyperledger Fabric network in production

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I want to migrate from levelDB to couchDB in a blockchain in production using Hyperledger Fabric.

If I change settings from levelDB to couchDB, should I lose all my data previously stored in couchDB ? If not, is there any possible migration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have also had the same several times. I have considered and tried many methods, but the easiest way is to create a new peer(+`couchdb`).

1. After creating a peer of the same organization, join existing channels
2. The new peer receives and synchronizes the existing blockchain ledger (blockchain+stateDB...) using gossip protocol.
3. After all the ledgers are synchronized (copied), delete the existing `goleveldb` peer.

- In the case of a new peer, you can use same configuration (crypto, etc.), with only different endpoints (container_name, etc.).
- If you have to use the endpoint of an existing peer, after the above process, the endpoint of the newly created peer is changed to the same value as the existing peer.